# Imagemagik Change an images dpi from 400 to 72

Tags: imagemagick, dpi

I have an image on my server which I know the dpi of and if it's too high I want to size it down to 72
I still want to keep the same height and width of the image. 
Any ideas?

I've played around with -resample -units and -density but don't seem to be getting anywhere and can't find any answers.
Anyone out there that can help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=11255&p=36566) using density should work

Comment: For completeness sake you could give an answer yourself and describe what was the issue and how you solved it.

Comment: I'm usually pretty good at reading the manual, but I can't get this to work.  Can you provide an example syntax?

Comment: @Kevin, can you reopen the question and describe your problem in detail? As stated (I have checked) the linked solution works. Without further data I can not guess what is wrong at your side (short of retype error or maybe ImageMagick version issue)

Answer (score 0):

If you know the target dpi and the width/height (in pixels) then you can just resize the image that meets those targets.